# Типизация и неприсвоенное значение

Tags: python, python-3.x, typing

Как обозначить тип переменной, которая может быть не присвоена?

Нужно выполнить ack последней cmd посланной в yield.

```
import asyncio

class Cmd1():
    value = 1

q = asyncio.Queue()
q.put_nowait(Cmd1())
q.put_nowait(Cmd1())


def ack(cmd):
    print(cmd)


async def gena():
    cmd = None
    try:
        while True:
           cmd = await q.get()
           print(cmd)
           yield cmd.value
    finally:
        if cmd :
            ack(cmd)


async def main():
    async for cmd in gena():
        break

asyncio.run(main())
```

Если сделать так `cmd: Cmd1|None = None` то подчеркивает красным `cmd.value`. Если `cmd: Cmd1` то не могу присвоить None.

```
"value" is not a known member of "None" Pylance report OptionalMemberAccess
```

Как обозначить тип cmd, чтоб тест проходило и не усложнять при этом рантайм?

Или как переписать эту конструкцию?

На данный момент так:

```
async def gena():
    cmd = None # type: ignore
    try:
        while True:
           cmd : Cmd1 = await q.get()
           print(cmd)
           yield cmd.value
    finally:
        if cmd :
            ack(cmd)
```

Comment: Вы аннотировали cmd как Cmd1 или None. Поэтому теперь на строке yield cmd.value надо учитывать оба варианта. Когда пришел None и когда пришел Cmd1. Например добавить ту же проверку if cmd

Comment: None прийти не может, а лишняя проверка это лишняя проверка

Comment: Вы сами в коде присваиваете cmd = None. Значит cmd может быть None для статических анализаторов.

Comment: Да и это не лишняя проверка в блоке finally. Без нее по-моему никуда. Надо ведь обработать ситуацию исключения на первой же итерации. Если так принципиально можно вынести первое получение cmd из цикла и обработать отдельно. Тем самым убрать эту проверку, но увеличить размер кода.

Comment: при исключении до yield не дойдет и попадет в блок finally и там эта проверка есть

Comment: А, я подумал вы хотите вообще избавиться от проверок. Ниже я дал ответ только с этой проверкой за счет введения переменной, хранящей предыдущий результат.

Comment: я хочу научиться как правильно типизировать этот патерн или как избежать переменной c None

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы не ругалось на переопределение cmd можно так

```
async def gena():
    result_cmd: Cmd1 | None = None
    try:
        while True:
           cmd: Cmd1 = await q.get()
           result_cmd = cmd
           print(result_cmd)
           yield result_cmd.value
    finally:
        if result_cmd :
            ack(result_cmd)
```

Comment: это пока лучшее, но все же workaround

Answer (score 0):

Жаль, что вы не написали, какой у вас IDE, который подчёркивает красным.

Мой pycharm ничего не подчёркивает, поэтому не могу говорить наверняка.

Но, полагаю, что должно работать такое решение:

```
async def gena():
    cmd: Cmd1|None = None    # Здесь вот так
    try:
        while True:
           cmd: Cmd1 = await q.get()  # А здесь вот так
           print(cmd)
           yield cmd.value
    finally:
        if cmd :
            ack(cmd)
```

Конечно, при условии, что в очереди `q` у вас действительно могут оказаться только строго объекты типа `Cmd1`.

Comment: Ваш вариант пробовал - дает ошибку `Declaration "cmd" is obscured by a declaration of the same name Pylance reportGeneralTypeIssues`